# exporting single module as library with webpack

Tags: webpack

I've got a web-app with all the javascript bundled into webpack.

I want to expose a subset of methods to the user via a clientside api.

I thought I could do this via a library

```
 output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'https://localhost:3000',
    library: 'myLibrary'
  }
```

Doing this, I can get `myLibary` in the console, but it is an empty object. I don't want every method in my bundle exposed publicly, but I'd like to specific public methods available, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export, what you want to expose, in your entry point. It works just like regular exports and you can include only the ones you want. For example with this entry point:

```
import module1 from './module';
import publicModule from './otherModule';
import privateModule from './privateModule';

function privateFun() {
  console.log('not exposed');
}

export function publicFun() {
  console.log('is exposed as myLibrary.public');
}

// Re-export, with possible rename
export { publicModule, module1 as firstModule };
```

Only the things you export are exposed, if you want to export other modules you import and re-export them. In this case you'll have access to the following properties:

```
myLibrary.firstModule
myLibrary.publicFun
myLibrary.publicModule
```